# Logarithm power rule does not provide a complete solution. Have the logarithm rules failed me?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, absolute-value

I am solving this question:

$log_3(m-7)^2 = 4$

There are *two ways* to solve it.

**The first way (expand the brackets):**

$log_3(m^2 -14m + 49) = 4$
$m^2 - 14m + 49 = 3^4$
$m^2 - 14m - 32 = 0$
$m = 16,-2$

And both of these are valid solutions, if substituted into the original equation.

**The second way (using logarithm power rule):**

$2log_3(m-7) = 4$
$log_3(m-7) = 2$
$m-7 = 3^2$
$m-7 = 9$
$m = 16$

Which provides one solution, but misses the other solution.

**My question is, where does the second solution fail, and why?**

I have played around with these graphs in Desmos, and expect the problem lies the moment I apply the power rule. (Desmos only draws one branch of the logarithm function once I apply the power rule). I've discovered that I can solve this by writing $2log_3(|m-7|) = 4$ (with an absolute value) and I suspect that might be what I am *supposed* to do, but cannot for the life of me understand why, and this is not the way I was taught the logarithmic power rule in highschool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution failed because you should have written $\log_3(m-7)^2 = 2\log_3 |m-7|$. Be sure to always have positive argument in the log!

Comment: Thanks @DodoDuQuercy, but is the |m-7| always there? (i.e. We start with $log_3(|m-7|)^2 = 4$), or do we only bring it in once we use the logarithm power rule? It makes sense, but this is new for me and I have to wrap my head around the idea..

Comment: Whether $x$ is negative or positive there is no problem writing $\log_3(x^2)$ since $x^2 \geq 0$ (if $x=0$, the value is minus infinity). But if you want to use the property that for all positive $y$, $\log (y^2) = 2 \log y$, you obviously have to take $y = |x|$ so that $y$ is positive. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes that helps thank you.

I am still a little bedazzled over why this small important note (that the absolute value is required for literally just this one specific logarithm rule) is not part of my country's highschool formula sheet (e.g. see here: https://www.nzqa.govt.nz/nqfdocs/ncea-resource/exams/2016/91577-frm-2016.pdf), but I will just have to find out why that is myself. Thanks

Comment: Don’t be too troubled about it, it’s merely required so that $\log y$ makes sense, the logarithm being defined on the positive real numbers only ;) (at least in real analysis)

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(x^2)=2\log(x)$$ is wrong as it does not work for $x<0$, due to the domain of the logarithm.

You can write

$$\log(x^2)=2\log(|x|).$$

---

Using complex numbers, the situation is a little different. If $x<0$,
$$\log(x)=\log(-x)+i\pi$$

and
$$2\log(x)=2\log(-x)+2i\pi.$$

The extra term $2i\pi$ is somewhat harmless as it is a logarithm of $1$.

Comment: One should however be careful when using complex logarithm, as it is not uniquely determined and as in consequence, even if you have have chosen a particular determination, you will not always have $\log (z_1 z_2) = \log z_1 + \log z_2$. Using complex logarithm requires having a few notions of complex analysis and I don't think it should be involved in basic real analysis. Of course this is only my opinion!

Comment: @DodoDuQuercy: I am in no way advocating that usage.